# alt+ctrl+f4 not working on visual studio 2005? but it did work previously

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In VisualStudio .net (say 2005)
I have this shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> which closes all the opened windows. (Already mapped to window.closealldocuments)
and another one <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close all but this window.

Now both shortcuts used to work on my previous workstation.
Both having winxp 32.And i work on sv 2005 on both.
But on this new machine, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> does not seem to propagate to Visual studio, like there's some other application or the explorer mapping this key to something else, and it's not propagating the event to vs process.
I know about the 'tools -> options...keyboard' in VS, but when I press the combination in the 'press shortcut keys:' field..
it would receive these combinations: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5->F10</kbd> but won't receive these: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1->F4</kbd>. 
It's like you didn't press nothing.
So now... any ideas?

Comment: Check the keyboard mappings in Tools/Options.

Comment: Use Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab.  Start killing processes one-by-one to find the one that's sucking the keystroke.

Comment: correct , thanks hans passant, would you answer the post to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was a process that probably was receiving the key combination and not propagating it to the rest of applications.

in my case it was hkcmd.exe (intel's graphic something ) that captures key combinations to do certain things like display rotation and such.

anyway thanks hans passant for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

These mappings aren't hard coded.  Not sure what happened, but it is easy to remap them.  Just go to Tools -> Options then:

[image: options dialog]

Click in the top indicated text box, then press the key combination, and select the appropriate command for it.  I like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to close the document and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> for all.

Comment: this is a 2010 dialog, but I believe it is still relatively the same as in 2005.

Answer (score 0):

You can set any hotkeys manually in any version of visual studio, just go to Tools->Options...-> Keyboard and assign any command to keys sequence