# Configuration Error after deploy to local C drive

Tags: asp.net, deployment, localhost

any have any idea why configuration error will prompt out after I click on Login.aspx?

[image]

[image]

[image]

your comment is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Try This In menu:

Website -> Start Options -> build tab -> Select Target Framework in Dropdown box (.NET FrameWork 4)

[image]

If website option isn't visible then you can try like this way too:

[image]

[image]

Comment: which menu do you mean?

Comment: my visual studio Menu dont have Website only have Window, and there is no Start Option. herm?

Comment: I have added the images. Go through it.

Comment: If website option is not visible then press shift+F4

Comment: mine is shown as PROJECT, and dont have Start Option, but do have properties, I clicked in, its similiar as urs but in the build tab dont have Target Framework. I added some image on my question.

Comment: If Shift+F4 doesn't work then you have to assign the command. Just go to Tools -> Options then: Press Shift+F4(Property Page) in the 'Press Shorcut Key' textbox then assign it. Or visit the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804356/altctrlf4-not-working-on-visual-studio-2005-but-it-did-work-previously

Comment: Remove the attribute targetframework="4.0" as In the first image of yours there is version information and it's 2.0 and you are trying to use 4.0 means either you haven't installed the 4.0 framework or framework 2.0 is set to default.

Comment: I tried, the thing come out as the image I shown above.. and I do deleted targetframework="4.0" and its throw me another error again regarding configuration. its seems like never end. :(

Comment: I am adding few more images to go at website property page. Have a look at it.

Comment: I done it d, coz mine does not use the way you do, need to change the framework to 2.0. mine have to change at ISS there. Thanks for your efford!!!

Comment: but I think yoursis one of the way of doing it also, therefor I will make as answer.